# Is there any GUI for per-neuron editing

Tags: neural-networks, programming-languages

I couldn't find GUI for precise "artificial neural-network alike" structures, which could supports neuron naming, synapse naming, import of external functions or code fragments and debugging. It would be ideal if synapses also could pass not only float values, but user-defined structures too. Optimization, GPU-computing is irrelevant (and probably impossible with such features).
Is such thing exists? I'm thinking about writing one myself, for my needs. And most probably I will...

Why do I need such features? For testing concept of construction of kind-of-neural logic programming. I'm sure there is also should exists programming languages with such paradigm, but I also don't know how to find them, google would mostly give me info about common artificial neural networks.

Comment: What do you mean by per neuron editing? Does it mean  you will create a ANN and it'll show the structure pictorially and the derivatives, weights, etc?

Comment: Yes, and besides showing weights, I mostly need to be able to see textual tags for neurons and their connections, not just "1, 2, 3 ... etc", but actual user defined names.

Comment: I had thought about creating one, the problem is the GUI...It's very tough syntactically to create a interactive gui like drag and drop (in python), did you make any headway though?

Comment: Well, kinda. I'm using C#+WPF with MVVM pattern and I've selected appropriate open source projects, currently I'm modelling data with UI. Interactive UI isn't a problem (at least in selected environment), but I want my project to support both UI+code editing mode (i.e. possibility to create and edit networks either by mouse or keyboard, depending on which way is more comfortable).

Comment: Also, I've found that this paradigm is called dataflow oriented programming. And I've found that most languages using this paradigm is mostly visual languages, which I find quite inconvenient (because it's much more convenient to write purely textual code for development and use visual for debugging and minor fixing).